# Jsoup - How can I get the direct children using Jsoup but not the subchildren?

Tags: groovy, jsoup

XML is as following, I just care about the first level for the `<a><b></b></a>`, notice: in the sub node `<d></d>`, there is also the same nodes. This is the question.

```
<a>
    <b>b1</b>
    <b>b2</b>
    <d>
        <a>
            <b>d_a_b1</b>
        </a>
        <a>
            <b>d_a_b2</b>
        </a>
    </d>
    <c>c</c>
</a>
```

I just want to get the value of a > b, so I used the Jsoup selector to select, the following is the code:

```
def str2 = '''
<a>
    <b>b1</b>
    <b>b2</b>
    <d>
        <a>
            <b>d_a_b1</b>
        </a>
        <a>
            <b>d_a_b2</b>
        </a>
    </d>
    <c>c</c>
</a>'''

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str2)
doc.select("a > b").each {
    println it.text()
}
```

but the result is that the selector also found the nodes under `<d> </d>` node, this is not what I cared.. The result I want to get is:

```
b1
b2
```

and the actual result is:

```
b1
b2
d_a_b1
d_a_b2
```

Can anyone help to just select the first level of the nodes? Any comment is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with groovy, but you can select the first level children like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s)

Element a = doc.select("a").first()
System.out.println(doc)
Elements aChildren = a.children()

for(Element element : aChildren) {
    println element.select("b").text()
}
```

But i think there is another problem with your example. Jsoup will parse your XML like this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a> <b>b1</b> <b>b2</b> 
   <d> 
   </d></a>
  <a> <b>d_a_b1</b> </a> 
  <a> <b>d_a_b2</b> </a>  
  <c>
   c
  </c> 
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see your `<a>` tag closed right after the tag `</d>`. It's because Nested `<a>`'s do not exist in HTML(it will mean Nested links which are not logical) and JSoup will fix it for you.

I hope this will help. As I said I am not familiar with `groovy`. So I may make some syntactical or maybe logical mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I just use this strategy: Element a = doc.select("a").first()
also thanks for your detailed explanation.